# What's the purpose of the .vim-force.com folder / session.properties file in my DX Project?

Tags: salesforcedx

I recently started seeing the `.vim-force.com` folder showing up on my DX projects, and the subsequent `session.properties` file is created there as well, but is usually blank.

What does this folder & file do for my DX project?

Comment: My guess is someone is using the [vim-force plugin](https://github.com/neowit/vim-force.com) and has committed related files to your source code repository. If that is the case and you are not using vim these do nothing for you. If you are using the plugin, I would suspect these files should not have been added to source control. NB: This is all speculation.